# Django views rendering just one page and wont render the rest

Tags: python, html, django, url, view

So im using django 1.8 on macosx and i have problem while configuring html, namely when i try to load another page except one that is set at default one(index is the default one), it just refreshes the default one i have set in urls.py and i cant access any other page except that one but in the url bar i can see that im accesing the proper html file because it says so but the page is not changing....heres my code:

app/urls.py-----------

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^projects/', views.projects, name='projects'),
    url(r'^services/', views.services, name='services'),
    url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name='about'),
```

these are all the pages im trying to install
main urls.py-------------
    from app import views

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^',include('app.urls')),

]
```

and this is my views.py-----------

```
def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'app/template/contact.html',{})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'app/template/about.html',{})

def projects(request):
    return render(request, 'app/template/projects.html',{})

def services(request):
    return render(request, 'app/template/services.html',{})

def index(request):
    return render(request, "app/template/index.html",{})
```

Comment: Not clear whats happening. Can you access any other url if you type that on the browser?

Comment: The behaviour you describe would only happen with "about" in this code, you would be able to access "contact", "projects" and "services" fine.

Comment: yes but just the index one i set to default or any other i set to default i can acces but when i try to acess about.html, url changes but i get the code from index.html @Walucas

Comment: @MilanRasovic, what happens if you access the urls like `/contact/`?

Comment: @Sean Francis N. Ballais nothing it is the same i can send a scrrenshot url changes but i get same index.html page

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais but if i put about.html to be my default page it is the same it will just load about.html insted of everyone and url will change

Comment: Man you confirm that the contents of the other templates are not the same as `index.html`?

Comment: `(r'', include...`, `(r'^$', index)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/

you need $ to end the string. In your case he link all thats starts with all.

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

you views.py:

```
def contact(request):
    return render(request, 'app/contact.html',{})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'app/about.html',{})

def projects(request):
    return render(request, 'app/projects.html',{})

def services(request):
    return render(request, 'app/services.html',{})

def index(request):
    return render(request, "app/index.html",{})
```

Comment: Good catch, mate!

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in instabook.urls(main urls.py), Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^contact/ [name='contact']
^projects/ [name='projects']
^services/ [name='services']
^$ [name='index']
^about/ [name='about']
^assets\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, about.html, didn't match any of these. @Nico Zimmer

Comment: I get that error when i type the solution@SeanFrancisN.Ballais

Comment: Do you try http://nameorip:port/about or http://nameorip:port/about.hmtl?

Comment: where ? @NicoZimmer

Comment: you wrote: The current path, about.html, didn't match any of these. You can´t acces the html-file direcly. You should use nameofyoupage/about/

Comment: yes i tried it it wont do it....maybe it is something with my settings file? this is from my settings.py            
ROOT_URLCONF = 'instabook.urls' is this good ? @NicoZimmer

Comment: Do you have add you app in you settings.py?

Comment: @NicoZimmer and this is templates from settings.py TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

Comment: @NicoZimmer yes i have added app

Comment: Where is you html file? Normaly is its in APPNAME/templates/APNAME/about.html
Then you can link it in views like app/about.html

Comment: yes i have placed it exactly there.... can you check my views.py did i link it good? i think that is it? @NicoZimmer

Comment: i chance my answer. In you views.py you wrote app/template... 
you do not need /template/

Comment: He can´t find the template. Something is wrong in you pfad. I can´t see it. Mabey you can read the docs to find the right way. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: ok thank you for your time spent to solve my issue ! i will try to figure it out! What did you type something is wrong in your pfad? is that a typo?